# List of students separated by gender in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table `tblstudent`.

```
ID |Name    |Gender

 1 |John  D |Male

 2 |Jane  D |Female

 3 |Joab  C |Male
```

How can I show on the report, using Crystal Reports, that it will look like this:

```
Male

 John D

 Joab C

Female

 Jane D
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would use the `Group Expert` feature within Crystal Reports.

I'll try and give a step by step guide on how to do this.

1. Add your command. I have done this by using a simple `SELECT` statement:

   ```
   SELECT ID
         ,Name
         ,Gender
   FROM tblstudents
   ```
2. From the menu within Crystal Reports select `Report` and then `Group Expert`. From here you can select which field you want to group by. In your case this is `Gender`:

   [image]
3. This will insert a new section with a `Group Header` and a `Group Footer`. You will want to add the `Name` field to the `Details` section:

   [image]
4. This is the output:

   [image]

I appreciate the report doesn't look very pretty. I'll leave the cosmetics to you.

Edited as per OP's comment with regards to numbering. There are two ways to do this. Either use the `Record Number` found in `Special Fields` or create a `Running Total`.

1. To use the `Record Number` found in `Special Fields` simply drag the field onto the report:

   [image]

> This list is found within the `Field Explorer` along with your `Database Fields`, `Formula Fields`, `Parameter Fields`, `Running Total Fields` and `Group Name Fields`.

This is the output:

[image]

2. Use a `Running Total Field`. Right click `Running Total Fields` within the `Field Explorer` and select `New`:

   [image]

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir this work for me. Perfectly. BTW. can i put a numbering beside the list of students?